# Adding blank space as one of my variable

Tags: c#

I want to write some data about the person's in a file. And while adding those data i want to add blank space if a particular data for that person is not available.

ex: I want to have "         " in place of SSN if person doesn't have one.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you writing to the file now? Show us some code so we know where's the problem...

Comment: i am using simple StreamWriter. i am getting the data in differemt objects and then adding them one by one in my file. everything is going well and now what i have is nothing in place of few fields for which the data is not available (not even spaces).

Comment: some people don't have SSN's? :)

Comment: Why would you want to add spaces for nonexistent data?  People doing stuff like that create work for me when importing "dirty data".  Need to scrub spaces from the ssn column because some joker filled it w/ spaces instead of just using Null.  If you need to display it why not using String.Empty()?

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... sorry for this kind of answer, but I really recommend you read up on file I/O. As Brad said, it's kinda unclear what your problem is.

I, for one, think your problem is not actually a problem: if you know how to print to the file all the other information, you surely must know how to add some blanks.

Again, sorry I'm not giving a straight answer, but trust me: I could tell you ten different ways of handling record-keeping when certain data is undefined for a record, and you would still learn much more (and much more solidly) reading a tutorial or two.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is writing out variables from an object, you could just use the String.IsNullOrEmpty method before you return the value you want to write.

Something like

```
return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SSN) ? SSN : " ";
```